# Override AndroidManifest.xml attributes from merged manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a library project and 2 application projects. I have activities declared in library project's AndroidManifest.xml and have `manifestmerger.enabled` set so the library manifest is merged with the two application manifests.

I want to override an activity attribute in application manifest. Specifically, I have the following declaration in library project's manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name=".sample.Activity1"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  .... />
```

And I want to override `hardwareAccelerated` attribute in one of the application project to `false`.

Putting the same activity declaration but with `hardwareAccelerated="false" in the application manifest causes an error when building:

```
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Merging manifests from project and 4 libraries.
[mergemanifest] Error: [AndroidManifest.xml:32, AndroidManifest.xml:57] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=.sample.Activity1] element:
```

Apparently, manifestmerger only allows you to merge manifest files and no mechanism for overriding declaration. Giving the use case I am trying to achive, what would be the alternatives that allows me to specify different values for an activity without having to duplicate activity declaration in both application projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently `manifest merger` fails if you have conflicts on the `AndroidManifests` and there is no way to ignore conflicts.

In your case the simplest workaround is to declare a boolean resource that tells if hardware acceleration is enabled for the `Activity`.

**Library project:**

```
<bool name="hardware_acceleration_enabled">true</bool>
```

Now you need to declare your Activity only in the library project and override the resource value in the real project:

**Library project:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".sample.Activity1"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="@boolean/hardware_acceleration_enabled"
    .... />
```

**Real project:**

```
<bool name="hardware_acceleration_enabled">false</bool>
```

Comment: How do I define the <bool> property inside AndroidManifest? It doesn't seem to allow me to.

Comment: @ejel, it should be definde somewhere under `res/value` directory. Check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool

Comment: but if I have a activity listed in lib manifest and in application manifest I want to make it launcher then how is this possible?